# Put comments (footnotes) on facing page, it is possible?

Tags: xetex, linguistics, reledmac, reledpar

My question is more not about a specific problem, but rather, about a possibility of design.

Briefly, I want to put the footnotes (the comments) of one text in facing pages, 
like this

```
------------------------------------------------
Page 1              |             Page 2
                    |                      
Here the text       |         Here the comments
                    |                      
Lorem Ispum,        |          [1] bla is a word.
bla[1] bla bla      |
 Lorem[2]           |           [2] Lorem :)          
                    |                      
                    |                      
------------------------------------------------
```

I was reading the `reledmac`, `reledpar` documentation but I did not find a command (like `\footnote`, `\endnote`) that is able to put the comments on facing page. This commands exists ? Or I will need to insert each commentary in the standard way using the facing environment? I.e.:

```
\begin{Leftpage}

....

\end{Lefpage}

\Pages
```

Comment: Paracol can be used to put notes in a separate column (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413580/how-to-correctly-change-the-side-that-marginpar-appears-per-case/414186?s=5|0.0000#414186).  It can also put columns on alternating pages (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425097/side-by-side-pages-synchronised-by-heading/425104?s=2|0.0000#425104).

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130175/35864

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's is different, the "footnotes" need to appear at the body text of the odd page, not in margin as the first link. The second answer is the naïve attempt that I already had, but not so nice, because will carry other problems with header, page numbering etc.

Comment: @moewe I want put footnotes in the body text of odd pages, and not in the same space in odd pages.

Comment: I don't quite understand, but I guess that doesn't matter since you seem to have found your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing @Fran answer, here a solution to get automatically paragraph of "foot"note synchroniszed with paragraph of main text, using reledpar, without inserting manually `\newpage` and have relatesd problems of synchronisation.

We just use the native features of reledpar, i.e synchornisation between left and right page.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[noend,noeledsec,series={}]{reledmac}
    \usepackage{reledpar}
    % To get numbered paragraph
    \numberpstarttrue
    \sidepstartnumtrue
    \begin{document}

    \begin{pages}
      \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
        Here the\footnotemark\  txt\footnotemark\ (§ 1)
        more text
        more text
        more text
        more text
        \pend
        \pstart
        Here the\footnotemark\  txt (§ 2)
        \pend
        \endnumbering
      \end{Leftside}
      \setcounter{footnote}{0}
      \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart
        \footnotemark Comment 1

        \footnotemark Comment 2
        \pend
        \pstart
        \footnotemark Comment 3
        \pend
      \endnumbering

      \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}

\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion! The result is very good! What I expected !

Comment: your'e welcome. I suggest to validate this answer as the result is what you expected

Answer (score 1):

A far I know, there are not packages for notes in next page , but you can make manually this using \footnotemark in odd pages and then in the even page a  `\footnotetext{note}` or  `\footnotemark[1] note` to make even-page-notes instead of true footnotes :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=7cm,paperwidth=6cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Here the text\par
Lore ipsum, bla\footnotemark\  bla bla\par
Lore\footnotemark\  
\newpage
Here the comments\par 
\footnotemark[1]  bla is a word\par
\footnotemark[2]  Lorem \texttt{:)} 
\footnotetext[1]{I daid that ``Bla'' is a word?}
\end{document}
```

Some more automatic could be put the notes  with `\afterpage{...}` of  the `afterpage` package, or may be with a [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page), but really I do not see the utility of this mess.

Other possibility, if you not not bibbliography in this document, could be use `thebibliography` environment  as fake notes:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[paperheight=7cm,paperwidth=6cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand\refname{\normalsize\normalfont Notes:}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{document}
Here the text\par
Lore ipsum, bla\cite{bla}  bla bla\par
Lore\cite{Lorem} 
\newpage
Here the comments\par 
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{bla}  bla is a word\par
\bibitem{Lorem}  Lorem \texttt{:)} 
\end{thebibliography}   
\newpage
Lore ipsum\cite{ipsum}, bla  bla bla\par
\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ipsum}  Ipsum is another word\par
\end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: cf my answer, that complet yours.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Very nice! :) I will try more, perhaps I can define some features :). If I get something, I will upload here.